# How can I draw a CART tree in Python, as I can in R?

Tags: python, r, graph, tree, scikit-learn

In R I can draw a graphical representation of a decision tree corresponding to a [CART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) model  directly using an API. For example [`prp`](http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf) will produce something like

[image]

But I can't find any similar API for the equivalent functionality in Python. For example, as near as I can tell neither `sklearn`'s `RandomForestClassifier` nor [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) have methods or drawing trees.

How can I get a graphical representation of a CART or random forest tree in Python?

Comment: Regression surfaces (whatever those are, I've just discovered them) would be great too.

Comment: It sure looks like there's a way to plot the tree in Python/scikit http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`export_graphviz`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) function.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.randn(10, 4)
y = array(["foo", "bar", "baz"])[np.random.randint(0, 3, 10)]
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42).fit(X, y)
export_graphviz(clf)
```

Now `dotty tree.dot` should display something like

[image: tree visualization]

Here's a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wIIiIMdqImq3rXG8gz8TawmLaoa9NaqD).

Comment: The parenthetical remark has me curious! Link? Timeframe? Package?

Comment: I can't get GraphViz to play nice with me. For example, in order to convert my exported dot to PNG, I need to restart my IPython kernel. Is there a way to create the dot, generate a PDF or PNG (or SVG) and load it into my IPython notebook so I can look at it?

Comment: And I'd also like to be able to replace the `X[.]`s with the corresponding column names from my data. Are there options for that.

Comment: Some follow up: (1) what about `RandomForestClassifier` trees; (2) how do I get the use the nice font in your example?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius (1) run the exporter on all `RandomForestClassifier.estimators_` (2) I think I used `dot -Tpng` instead of `dotty` for the pic.

Comment: I posted an answer which works for Jupyter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53546533/1840471

Answer (score 1):

This function will get the graph to show up in Jupyter notebooks:

```
# Imports
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image, display
import pydotplus

def jupyter_graphviz(m, **kwargs):
    dot_data = StringIO()
    export_graphviz(m, dot_data, **kwargs)
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
    display(Image(graph.create_png()))
```

For example:

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
import pandas as pd

iris = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y = iris.target
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
dtree.fit(df, y)

jupyter_graphviz(dtree, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True)
```

[image: Tree visualization]

Here's a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q0Ppj2izj6yPuJ49rXkDxWxM-yLfly98) in action, adapted from [this post](https://medium.com/@rnbrown/creating-and-visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-f8e8fa394176).